# How to limit adding values in array?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have created component **cart** and i want to add only 5 unique items in it.

```
 // this below line adds unique items to cart
 let uniqueObjArray = [...new Map(this.cartElements.map((item) => [item["id"], item])).values()];

        if (this.uniqueCartElements.length < 5) {
          this.uniqueCartElements = uniqueObjArray;
        }
```

the above code is working for first time only! but when i remove item from cart by using function
`handleRemove(event)` it doesn't work and adds unique items including removed item in the **cart**.

this is code:-

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { subscribe, MessageContext, publish } from 'lightning/messageService';
import createOrderMethod from '@salesforce/apex/CreateOrders.createOrderMethod'
import GetSelectedFoodItem from '@salesforce/messageChannel/AddFoodItemToCart__c';
import SendOrder from '@salesforce/messageChannel/SendOrder__c'
export default class Cart extends LightningElement {
    
    @track total = 0;
    subscription = null;
    

    @wire(MessageContext)
    messageContext;

    connectedCallback(){
        this.subscribeToMessageChannel();
    }
    renderedCallback(){
      let b = this.template.querySelector('.order-button')
      if (this.uniqueCartElements.length === 0) {
        b.disabled = true
      }else{
        b.disabled = false
      }

    }
    subscribeToMessageChannel(){
        this.subscription = subscribe(
            this.messageContext,
            GetSelectedFoodItem,
            (message) => this.handleMessage(message)
            );
    }

    cartElements = [];

    //use @track to track real time changes in element
    //This "uniqueCartElements = []" is used to keep orders
    @track uniqueCartElements = [] ;

    handleMessage(message){

        let cartItems = {};

        cartItems.id = message.itemId;
        cartItems.name = message.itemName;
        cartItems.quantity = message.itemQuantity;
        cartItems.price = message.itemPrice * message.itemQuantity;

        this.cartElements.push(cartItems);
        
        let uniqueObjArray = [...new Map(this.cartElements.map((item) => [item["id"], item])).values()];

        if (this.uniqueCartElements.length < 5) {
          this.uniqueCartElements = uniqueObjArray;
        }


        let itemPrice = message.itemQuantity * message.itemPrice;
        
        let result = 0;
        this.uniqueCartElements.forEach(uniqueItem => {
          result = result + uniqueItem.price;
        });
       
        this.total = result;
    }

    handleRemove(event){

       let  value = event.target.value;
      
       let getindex = (index => {
        return index.id == value;
       })

       let indexValue = this.uniqueCartElements.findIndex(getindex);
     
       let deleteVal = this.uniqueCartElements.splice(indexValue,1);
      
        this.total = this.total - JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(deleteVal[0].price));

        this.cartElements = this.uniqueCartElements;
        console.log("this.cartElements:- ",JSON.stringify(this.cartElements));
    }


    handleOrders(){

      let orderlistArray = []
      for (const v of this.uniqueCartElements) {
        let orderlist = JSON.stringify(`${v.name}, ${v.quantity}`)
        orderlistArray.push(orderlist)
      }

      createOrderMethod({orderName : JSON.stringify(this.uniqueCartElements)})
      .then(result =>{
        // console.log("result order:- ", JSON.stringify(result));
      })
      .catch(error =>{
        // console.log("error order:- ", JSON.stringify(error));
      })
      this.uniqueCartElements.length = 0

    }

}
```

this is html:-

```
<!-- sldsValidatorIgnore -->
<!-- sldsValidatorIgnore -->
<template>
   <lightning-card title="Cart">
       <ul>
           <template for:each={uniqueCartElements} for:item="uniqueCartElement">
            <li key={uniqueCartElement.id}>
                {uniqueCartElement.name}
                <span>Quantity{uniqueCartElement.quantity}</span>
                <span>price:{uniqueCartElement.price}</span>
                <lightning-button label="Remove" value={uniqueCartElement.id} onclick={handleRemove}></lightning-button>
            </li>
           </template>
        </ul>
        <p>Total $ {total}</p>
        <lightning-button label="Order" class="order-button" onclick={handleOrders}></lightning-button>
   </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The LWC framework may not properly track prototype methods like splice.

If you want it to track the addition or removal of elements in the array, you need to assign the array again. Like this:

```
let deleteVal = this.uniqueCartElements.splice(indexValue,1);
this.uniqueCartElements = this.uniqueCartElements;
```

Based on my reading [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reactivity_fields), it is supposed to track all changes to an array. However, try my suggested change and see if it works for you.

Also, if the above doesn't work, use the spread operator to fully recreate the array. This is not generally recommended, as it's an expensive operation. However, for this case, I think you will not see any issues with performance.

```
this.uniqueCartElements = [...this.uniqueCartElements];
```